# С прописной или строчной буквы пишется "О/одиссеева Итака"?

Tags: грамотность

Как пишется "О/одиссеева Итака": с прописной или строчной "О"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[С прописной](http://lingvanotes.blogspot.com.au/2012/12/blog-post.html). Но надо сказать, что правило на этот счет не самое очевидное, и вопрос очень правомерен. Многие подобные прилагательные, образованные от имен, (и даже сами имена: "современные онегины") должны писаться со строчной буквы, тогда как в английском они почти всегда пишутся с прописной.

Comment: Could you please copy the relevant portions of the text behind the link to your answer? Thanks!

Comment: +1, though I should also note that the rule as it is quoted in the article is quite misleading. *фалеков гендекасиллаб* and *декартовы координаты* are not capitalized. It's not the ending that matters, but whether the adjective is possessive or descriptive.

Comment: @Quassnoi, you are right (although it can probably be argued that your examples are 'idioms'), and if you have a better reference, I'll happily integrate it into the answer.